# jQuery - Adding/removes classnames from the element and togling active class on the button

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I need to change the `.important-element` to the same color as the same-name button has been pressed. I want to achieve this by adding `.red`, `.blue`, `.green` classnames to `.important-element` and also removing them if the other or same button has been pressed. I am not sure how to edit my jQuery code for this to work.

Important thing: upon pressing the button it needs to remove previously added classnames (just like jQuery code works right now with the buttons). In other words: if one button is already active, it needs to remove it added class names from `.important-element` upon pressing another button.

```js
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  $('button').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {width: 1190px;max-width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;}
button {outline: 0; /* only to remove the ugly blue outline in this demo */}
button.active {color: white;}
button.green.active {background:green;}
button.red.active {background:red;}
button.blue.active {background:blue;}

.important-element {padding:20px; width:240px; text-align:center;  background:grey; margin-top:30px; color:#FFF;}
.important-element.green {background:green}
.important-element.red {background:red}
.important-element.blue {background:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-filter-container">
    <button class="btn green">green</button>
    <button class="btn red">red</button>
    <button class="btn blue">blue</button>
</div>

<div class="important-element">i need to change with button click to the same collor as the button</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now the code should be right.

```js
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  var classname = $(this).attr('class');
  var split = classname.split(" ");
  var elementcolor = split[1];
  var colorStack = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];
  $('button').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $.each($(colorStack), function(index, value) {
    if ($('.important-element').hasClass(value)) {
      $('.important-element').removeClass(value);
    }
  });
  $('.important-element').addClass(elementcolor);
  $.each($(colorStack), function(index, value) {
    if (!$('button').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.important-element').removeClass(value);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.price-filter-container {
  width: 1190px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  outline: 0;
  /* only to remove the ugly blue outline in this demo */
}

button.active {
  color: white;
}

button.green.active {
  background: green;
}

button.red.active {
  background: red;
}

button.blue.active {
  background: blue;
}

.important-element {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.important-element.green {
  background: green
}

.important-element.red {
  background: red
}

.important-element.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-filter-container">
  <button class="btn green">green</button>
  <button class="btn red">red</button>
  <button class="btn blue">blue</button>
</div>

<div class="important-element">i need to change with button click to the same collor as the button</div>
```

Comment: You did it with "style" but I need to do it by changing the classnames. Can you help?

Comment: Updated my code example. Just have a look if it fits your expectations. If it fits please upvote or mark the question as answered so I will get some points :-) THX

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this code does not do one important thing. If you click any button, for e.g "red" and "important-element" get class "red" after you click "red" button again it should remove classname "red" from important-element, just like in my initial code, but it doesnt.

Comment: Updated my code example again. Please check it if it fits your needs.

Comment: Thx for the check. I made it a little bit handier with each loops and and array of the three colors. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you, Bernhard. My mistake was to put specific class name colors into my example. While your code does indeed answer this question, it is not what I wanted. So I have opened  a new question (but it instantly got flaged as duplicated, while in reality its different): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818673/toggle-and-remove-classnames-from-selected-element-by-pressing-the-button-and-ke?noredirect=1 here is a jsfidle from it https://jsfiddle.net/2km7cpq3/ maybe you can take a look and answer there?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simplified version:

```js
var colors = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ];
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var color = [ ...this.classList ].filter((className) => colors.includes(className))[0];
  var otherColors = colors.filter((colorName) => colorName !== color);
  $('.important-element').removeClass(otherColors.join(' ')).toggleClass(color);
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {width: 1190px;max-width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;}
button {outline: 0; /* only to remove the ugly blue outline in this demo */}
button.active {color: white;}
button.green.active {background:green;}
button.red.active {background:red;}
button.blue.active {background:blue;}

.important-element {padding:20px; width:240px; text-align:center;  background:grey; margin-top:30px; color:#FFF;}
.important-element.green {background:green}
.important-element.red {background:red}
.important-element.blue {background:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-filter-container">
    <button class="btn green">green</button>
    <button class="btn red">red</button>
    <button class="btn blue">blue</button>
</div>

<div class="important-element">i need to change with button click to the same collor as the button</div>
```

If you like to use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), that might make it even easier:

```js
var colors = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ];
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var color = this.dataset.color;
  var otherColors = colors.filter((colorName) => colorName !== color);
  $('.important-element').removeClass(otherColors.join(' ')).toggleClass(color);
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {width: 1190px;max-width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;}
button {outline: 0; /* only to remove the ugly blue outline in this demo */}
button.active {color: white;}
button[data-color="green"].active {background:green;}
button[data-color="red"].active {background:red;}
button[data-color="blue"].active {background:blue;}

.important-element {padding:20px; width:240px; text-align:center;  background:grey; margin-top:30px; color:#FFF;}
.important-element.green {background:green}
.important-element.red {background:red}
.important-element.blue {background:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-filter-container">
    <button class="btn" data-color="green">green</button>
    <button class="btn" data-color="red">red</button>
    <button class="btn" data-color="blue">blue</button>
</div>

<div class="important-element">i need to change with button click to the same collor as the button</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this code does not do one important thing. If you click any button, for e.g "red" and "important-element" get class "red" after you click "red" button again it should remove classname "red" from important-element, just like in my initial code, but it doesnt.

Comment: I implemented that requirement and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You did. The problem was that my question was more like an example, and colors here were just used for example purposes. Yet, your code is strictly for colors and only works with these specific class names. I tried to be more precise in this question, if you can please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818673/toggle-and-remove-classnames-from-selected-element-by-pressing-the-button-and-ke

Comment: Please reopen my question that you just closed. As i posted it and was typing reply for you.

Comment: You can put anything in this array. It's just used to distinguish the classes you want from the classes you don't want (e.g. `.btn`)

Comment: Could you put the comment there, to reason the reopen process? I can't reopen your question on my own anyway. It depends on the votes.

Comment: My other question is completely different, please take a look again. I spent more than an hour trying to make it understandable as possible. It also has different jQuery code. I understand that this might be very simple for you (just like html/css is for me) but I am struggling with jQuery and need help that question. This did not solve anything for me as you have used variables while I have specific class names. So, please reopen that question and if you can - take a look.

Comment: Copy your explanation from my answer over there, so I can vote to reopen it based on your explanation.