# Toglle different classnames of an element upon activating a button

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

```js
$(function () {
    $("#my-buttons").on('click', 'button', function () {
      $('button').not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-display', function () {
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("hidden shown");
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-select', function () {
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("selected");
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-size', function () {
        $(".awesome-element").toggleClass("small big");
    });
});
```

```css
#my-buttons {width: 1190px;max-width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;}
button {outline: 0;}
button.active {color:green;}
.awesome-element {padding:20px; width:240px; text-align:center;  background:grey; margin-top:30px; color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-buttons">
    <button class="btn-display">#1 toggle hidden-shown</button>
    <button class="btn-select">#2 add/remove select</button>
    <button class="btn-size">#3 toggle big small</button>
    
    
</div>

<div class="awesome-element hidden small">when a button is presed -  respective classname must be toggled, while previously added classname changed to default</div>
```

As you can see, I have four functions in my jQuery. They almost work correctly, but have some mistakes:

1. I think all of them should be in single function and not in four different.
2. If you press (once) button #2 it adds `selected` to `awesome-element` but if you press button #1 or #3 it does not remove this element. It stays `selected` but it shouldnt.
3. Same with other buttons. By default `awesome-element` is `hidden` and `small` (see original HTML) so if you press button #3 or #1 it toggles respective class (hidden<->shown and small<->big). So if you make `awesome-element` big (by clicking on button #3) and then click on button #2 or #1 it stays big, when it should go to default -> which is small.

Please reopen this question, since this one does not answer it [jQuery - Adding/removes classnames from the element and togling active class on the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68805166/jquery-adding-removes-classnames-from-the-element-and-togling-active-class-on)

Comment: You can definitely wrap all in one `$(function () { }`

Comment: Why do you use `$("#my-buttons")` once and `$('body')` in all the other cases?

Comment: I am basically lost and `point.2` and `point.3` I dont know how to remove added classnames after they have been added.

Comment: Why do you use $("#my-buttons") once and $('body') in all the other cases? Simply cause i am a nooby :)

Comment: You can remove class names via `removeClass()` but I guess, that's not what you wanted to know, is it?

Comment: Well maybe I should make open a new question and just copy this one there?

Comment: `point.2` and `point.3`?

Comment: No, copy your explanation from my answer over here. I understood it, so maybe others do as well.

Comment: Stakcoverflow is already angry that we are using "extended discussions in comments". I have 3 mistakes that my jQuery code does not do and have listed them in bullet points. So, yeah, I need help with them.

Comment: You can put the toggle classes in [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) and reference them in the callback.

Comment: The HTML code should not be changed. Seriously this should be such a common task. On a website u press a button and that button does something to a targeted element. You press another button and targeted element changes again while removing what previous button did to it.

Comment: Seriously, YOU wanted your code to be simplified. That IS a simpification. Apart from that, you didn't mention you don't want to change the HTML.

Comment: I can't answer your question since it's closed. I told you multiple times to post your explanation for re-opening under this very question

Comment: Can you at least [edit] your question and make the adjustment I proposed to your code (post the updated code at the bottom of your question)?

Comment: "I told you multiple times to post your explanation for re-opening under this very question" - i do not know where to do that. Seriously deleting this question and opening same one but new, would have been so much easier. I should probably do that.

Comment: You might run into the same problem you did here: People consider it spam since you posted a similar question just hours before.

Comment: Let hope not. I am gonna post question now and give you the link here. If you can answer it, maybe other people will not flag it as duplicate

Comment: Btw now I understood what you were asking, but i can not answer this question so you could reopen it. The website just does not let me. And it does not let me post a question since it is a duplicate. I have posted everything in this jsfidle. Maybe you could alter it? https://jsfiddle.net/2km7cpq3/

Comment: I cleaned up your code based on my comments but that doesn't replace asking a question on SO: https://jsfiddle.net/w5Ln6fqc/ Of course, you can't reopen your own question. I only asked to comment here with an explanation why you think, the question was accidentely closed like you did under my answer to your other question. It was well written, just in the wrong place because those you want to re-open your question wouldn't see it there.

Comment: You mean like so? Please reopen my question since that duplicate does not answer my question. My other question is completely different, please take a look again. I spent more than an hour trying to make it understandable as possible. It also has different jQuery code. I understand that this might be very simple for you (just like html/css is for me) but I am struggling with jQuery and need help that question. This did not solve anything for me as you have used variables while I have specific class names. So, please reopen that question.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/w5Ln6fqc this does not answer 2) and 3). When you activated the other button - previous class name stays, but it shouldnt.

Comment: "You mean like so?" - Exactly. I voted to reopen your question. Everything else is beyond my power now.

Comment: Any chance you can help with 2) and 3)?

Comment: You can do `$(".awesome-element").removeClass([ ...$(".awesome-element").get(0).classList ].filter((className) => className !== 'awesome-element').join(' ').addClass(newClass);`

Comment: Can you please alter the jsfidle link? :( I dont yet fully understand the syntax of jquery to alter it on my own. I am learning by looking at correct examples (my way of learning)

Comment: Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/34ojL58c/

Comment: :( it has several mistakes. If you press #1btn it does not toggle hidden/shown instead it prints both classnames, resulting in `awesome-element hidden shown`

2. if you press #2ndbtn it must add `selected` on first press but one second it should remove `selected`

Comment: Well, you can only really toggle two classes if one is set and another is not, so that after toggling the one isn't set and the other one is. So what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I made this one really simple https://jsfiddle.net/8x9g6tzs/

We have two buttons. Each adds a unique class. If i press button #1 it removes/adds classname `selected`. now when `awesome-element` has class `awesome-element selected` and i press  btn#2 i want `selected` to be removed and changed with classname from btn#2 `awesome-element shown`. I understand I can achiev this by adding addClass/removeClass IFs. But is there something like and "undo" function in jquery? Undo previously added classnames, like ctrl+z we use in notepad, sublime or w/e. Or should I achiev this with IFs?

Comment: Not that I know of: https://jsfiddle.net/g1L8anr6/

Comment: Thank you again, but this is just not working. It does not togle hiden-shown if you press btn1 it also removes all elements except 'awesome-element'. Remember this is just an example. My real code contains like 6 classes in it `awesome-element epic-element big-element etc.` I guess i ll have to write something with tons of IFs. Wasted 3 days into this, makes me wanna tear my hair out. Nevertheless thank you for all your help.

Comment: I know html/css. I understand and can edit php. I need to start learning javascript. Maybe there are youtube/website courses would you suggest to a beginner?

Comment: You're welcome. You can try this one: https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp